# EF Core cannot creating Database :(

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I want to create database with code first technique using EF 3.1. However, no matter what I try in EF 6.0, the database [image]is not created.

Comment: Well, can you post what you tried so far? The code you posted does not create anything.

Comment: Post the relevant code in the question as text, not an image of just the DbContext. How do you use that DbContext? Did you use the `dotnet ef` command to create the database? Did you get an error? Or did you call `EnsureCreated` ?

Comment: How/why are you mixing EF 6 and EF Core? Those are 2 completely separate products.

Comment: First of all, I'm trying to use ef core. I have nothing to do with ef. Since my models are a bit long, I show the shortest in the example below.

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Core;


namespace Entities.Concrete
{
    public class Category:IEntity
    {
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Core
{
    public interface IEntity
    {
    }
}

Comment: The code below with IEntity is in the core layer
public class EfEntityRepositoryBase<TEntity, TContext> : IEntityRepository<TEntity>
        where TEntity : class, IEntity, new()
        where TContext : DbContext, new()
    {
        public void Add(TEntity entity)
        {
            //IDisposable pattern implementation of c#
            using (TContext context = new TContext())
            {
                var addedEntity = context.Entry(entity);
                addedEntity.State = EntityState.Added;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

Comment: nothing in business layer

Comment: I also tried context connettion = True, this time the connection with the database could not be established.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At first you need to create migration files with command `dotnet ef migrations add Initial`

Then you can manually create a new empty database `Adatech`. Or, if the specific case is to create database automatically during migration, you can add your own new migration (or modify `Initial` one, after it is created) and put there SQL CREATE DATABASE command there. (Don't forget to complement this by a rollback logic in Down() method)

Then apply this migration to your db: `dotnet ef database update`

Context itself doesn't do anything with your database, it is just a model of your database entities in scope of your application. Model that contains rules how this these entities should correlate with db.

More here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/migrations?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: when i try to follow doc- Build failed. Use dotnet build to see the errors